# PHP code not executing, new to PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

Last week I started playing around with LAMP Ubuntu and I didnt have any issues. Today some code wasn't working so I tried running this in index.php:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

This doesn't work when I connect to localhost in my browser, but it works in testphp.php at localhost/testphp.php

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What about `http://localhost/index.php`?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the code?

Comment: MAy be not for you...but it will be helpful for us if you provide code here

Comment: Obvious attempt, but did you try restarting the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that code doesn't get executed when you access http://localhost/, then you should try to add
`DirectoryIndex  index.html index.php`
to your apache's conf file.

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming the file to index.php

Comment: @chetan: i believe he's got the same point as zerkms' What about http://localhost/index.php?

Comment: I have a shortcut index.html that points to index.php, and localhost/index.html doesn't work. What could have happened to the shortcut that disabled php?